# Is there any way to control the volume (hardware buttons) of a paused cast video (android)

Tags: android, google-cast

I'm wondering if there is any way to pause a video and then control the volume (hardware buttons) of it?

Sub question:
Is there any way to control the volume of the cast even before a video has been selected?

Thanks

Comment: A not so elegant solution would be to read the current volume and set that to the current cast volume.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a connection to a cast device, you can control the volume on the cast device; there is no requirement to have any media started or paused or even loaded.

Comment: Well it's not quite working on my phone. When the media is not playing I can not control the volume on the cast. But then I noticed when I tried the same on the YouTube app I saw the same pattern. So I think I will skip that functionality.

Thank you for taking your time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
private CastContext mCastContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(@NonNull KeyEvent event) {
    return mCastContext.onDispatchVolumeKeyEventBeforeJellyBean(event)
            || super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```